# Building openlayers with custom controls

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a couple custom OpenaLayers 3 conrtrols which I wrote.
All of my controls extend the `ol.control.Control`.
I'm using requirejs to include open layers into my project, but when I try to do it the goog object is not defined.
I'm researching now how to make a cutom build of OpenLayers 3 so I can include with it, but I'm wandering if there is a way to do it with building my OpenLayers  3 version with every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial explains how to build OpenLayers along with your own project source files: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/doc/tutorials/closure.html

This should be enough to get you going.

You can also take a look at some other projects that compile OpenLayers with their own source code, as a way to get inspired to how to do your own implementation:

- OL3-Cesium: http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/
- Ngeo: https://github.com/camptocamp/ngeo

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for!